# How To Map Column Values where two others match? "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have one DataFrame, df, I have four columns shown below:

```
IDP1    IDP1Number    IDP2    IDP2Number
1       100           1       NaN
3       110           2       150
5       120           3       NaN
7       140           4       160
9       150           5       190
NaN     NaN           6       130
NaN     NaN           7       NaN
NaN     NaN           8       200
NaN     NaN           9       90
NaN     NaN           10      NaN
```

I want instead to map values from df.IDP1Number to IDP2Number using IDP1 to IDP2. I want to replace existing values if IDP1 and IDP2 both exist with IDP1Number. Otherwise leave values in IDP2Number alone.

```
The error message that appears reads, " Reindexing only valid with uniquely value Index objects
```

The Dataframe below is what I wish to have:

```
IDP1    IDP1Number    IDP2    IDP2Number
1       100           1       100
3       110           2       150
5       120           3       110
7       140           4       160
9       150           5       120
NaN     NaN           6       130
NaN     NaN           7       140
NaN     NaN           8       200
NaN     NaN           9       150
NaN     NaN           10      NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
# filter the data and create a mapping dict
maps = df.query("IDP1.notna()")[['IDP1', 'IDP1Number']].set_index('IDP1')['IDP1Number'].to_dict()

# create new column using ifelse condition
df['IDP2Number'] = df.apply(lambda x: maps.get(x['IDP2'], None) if (pd.isna(x['IDP2Number']) or x['IDP2'] in maps) else x['IDP2Number'], axis=1)

print(df)

   IDP1  IDP1Number  IDP2  IDP2Number
0   1.0       100.0     1       100.0
1   3.0       110.0     2       150.0
2   5.0       120.0     3       110.0
3   7.0       140.0     4       160.0
4   9.0       150.0     5       120.0
5   NaN         NaN     6       130.0
6   NaN         NaN     7       140.0
7   NaN         NaN     8       200.0
8   NaN         NaN     9       150.0
9   NaN         NaN    10         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks very much, intuitively what's happening here then?

Comment: we create a dict which maps `IDP1` to `IDP1Number` values. Then, using ifelse we check, if the value is `NA` in `IDP2Number` we replace it with value from the dict using the corresponding value from `IDP2`. You should print the result after every step to get the visual idea.

Comment: Will do, it makes sense. It gets around the issue of having different index sizes too which is super helpful!